# return global variable value set inside loop

Tags: c#

```
public class loginbal
{
  public static bool   match = false ;

  public bool check(string username, string password)
  {
        logindal LGD = new logindal();
        DataSet ds1= LGD.logincheck(username, password);

        int noofrows = ds1.Tables["login"].Rows.Count;

        for (int i = 0; i < noofrows; i++)
        {
            if ((ds1.Tables["login"].Rows[i]["username_l"].ToString() == username) && (ds1.Tables["login"].Rows[i]["password_l"].ToString() == password))
            {
                match = true;
            }
        }

    return match;
}
```

I want to return `match`  but its not affected with for loop set statement what i can do  to change match according to for loop value and return to method?

Comment: and why do you need a variable in the first place? just `return true` when you found a match. Also you are never resetting `match` to `false` so the method will always return `true` after you have found a match once.

Comment: Get rid of your `match` variable. Replace `match = true` with `return true`, and `return match` with `return false`. Presto.

Answer (score 2):

As [@BrokenGlass](https://stackoverflow.com/users/329769/brokenglass) and [@NullUserException](https://stackoverflow.com/users/396458/nulluserexception) have pointed out, there is no need for a variable `match`, much less a static one. Just return `true` if the loop finds a match. If it doesn't, return `false`.

```
public bool check(string username, string password)
{
    logindal LGD = new logindal();
    DataSet ds1= LGD.logincheck(username, password);

    int noofrows = ds1.Tables["login"].Rows.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < noofrows; i++)
    {
        if ((ds1.Tables["login"].Rows[i]["username_l"].ToString() == username)
            && (ds1.Tables["login"].Rows[i]["password_l"].ToString() == password))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: There's no need for .Equals as the .net compiler will do this anyway. Also I rather think returning instead a loop is bad practice as you can't write a flow diagram for the function.

Comment: there is a little difference between Equals and ==. One difference is if the string you call Equals on is null, a null exception will be thrown. Not so for ==.

Comment: @Ash - Removed the `.equals()` distinction. My mind was stuck in Java mode, thanks. As for returning in the loop, that can be the OP's call after reading your comment.